# T-SQL: Disable default FLOAT rounding when using Table with its View

Tags: t-sql

Good day!
Here is the problem of float rounding when I want insert data into Table using its View.
Data NEED to store as varchar in Table. 
Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTableFloat_E]
(
  [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [FloatField] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
)
```

View:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[TestTableFloat]
AS
SELECT  id
        ,Convert(float, FloatField) as FloatField
FROM dbo.TestTableFloat_E
```

The data, what I select from Table using its View - have to have float type (field FloatField).
I can't insert data into Table, if i need, I need do it with its View. So, I can't (this is task rule) insert data directly into Table, just with View. I create trigger to insert data:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_TestTableFloatInsert] 
   ON  [dbo].[TestTableFloat] 
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

insert into TestTableFloat_E (FloatField)
select FloatField
FROM INSERTED
```

Actions: I try insert data into TestTableFloat_E (table) with help of its View (TestTableFloat), rises trigger and insert data into table.
Problem: When I insert float number, I have rounding, that I don't need:

```
insert TestTableFloat (FloatField)
select 123.123456
```

I have 123,123 in the Table TesttableFloat. I need it doesn't round, I have to have 123.123456
What can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it store more digits, but it's going to switch to scientific notation:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_TestTableFloatInsert] 
   ON  [dbo].[TestTableFloat] 
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

insert into TestTableFloat_E (FloatField)
select CONVERT(varchar(100),FloatField,2)
FROM INSERTED
END
```

Which ends up storing `1.231234560000000e+002` into the table.

From [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

> When expression is float or real, style can be one of the values shown in the following table. Other values are processed as 0.
>
> 0 (default)
>   A maximum of 6 digits. Use in scientific notation, when appropriate.
>
> 1
>   Always 8 digits. Always use in scientific notation.
>
> 2
>   Always 16 digits. Always use in scientific notation.

---

*Insert usual caveats about futility of expecting float and a decimal representation of the same to always be exactly convertible, and of using inappropriate data types to store particular types of data*

---

It would appear the best data type to use for this data would be `decimal` with appropriate scale and precision, which is neither of the types you're working with. But you claim that those are the "required" types. E.g. if the view uses a decimal instead of a float, the stored `varchar(100)` value is exactly as expected.

Comment: Incredible... I thought nobody understand, what I wrote and want here. `select CONVERT(varchar(100),FloatField,2)` what I need. Thanks!!